# Can't get data from $http.post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

So basically, I have a form and I cannot fetch data typed into it.(I'm using angular and node.js) 
req.body
req.params are both empty
My html form :

```
<form ng-submit="sendTradelink()">
            <md-input-container class="md-accent">
                <label>Enter your tradelink</label>
                <input ng-model="tradelink">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-accent">Send</md-button>
        </form>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.sendTradelink = function () {
            Auth.send()
                .success(function (res) {
                    $location.path('/');
                });
        }
```

Service :

```
authFactory.send = function (tradelink) {
            return $http.post($api.url + 'tradelink', {tradelink: tradelink});
        };
```

Server side file where I want to work with data inserted into form:

```
  api.post('/tradelink', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.user.id);
    console.log(req.params);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({
      success: true,
      message: 'tradelink received'
    })
  });
```

logs for controlling, empty every time.

Comment: What is the server? Express? It does not by default parse the body.  You can use `body-parser` middleware, then access `req.body.tradelink`.

Comment: @Amadan Yes exactly, it's express. Thank you I will check it out tomorrow morning, 5 am here :(.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, Express does not parse the body. POST requests are much more complex that GET ones, so the parser lies in a separate package, `body-parser`:

```
npm install --save body-parser

// server.js
api.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({                                                                                                 
  extended: true
}));

api.post('/tradelink', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.tradelink);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Amadan answer is right. You also need to update the controller:

```
Auth.send($scope.tradelink)
```